# How to start QGIS after building & install on ubuntu 12.04 64bit?

Tags: qgis, linux

I am a newbie here.

I am running ubuntu 12.04 64bit, and build after the instruction, but i don't know  why can not launch qgis. Seem i successfully build $ install it.

below is the linux shell:

```
jack@jack:~/apps/bin$ sudo su
root@jack:/home/jack/apps/bin# qgis
The program 'qgis' can be found in the following packages:
 * qgis
 * qgis-plugin-grass
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
root@jack:/home/jack/apps/bin# ls
qbrowser  qgis  qgis_bench
root@jack:/home/jack/apps/bin#
```

Answer (score 2):

The output from ls indicates that you have a executable file in current directory, it can be run by typing `./qgis`.

When you run `qgis`, it is assumed that qgis is not in your [$PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
add repo son source.list  
deb     http://qgis.org/debian precise main  
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian precise main
```

teriminal---->

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 997D3880  
gpg --export --armor 997D3880 | sudo apt-key add -

apt-get update

apt-get install qgis
```

Answer (score 0):

According to qgis site if you want to install the latest release (recommended) :

1. $ `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`
2. $ `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable`
3. $ `sudo apt-get update`
4. $ `sudo apt-get install qgis`

If you're a newbie to the linux world you better avoid sudo as hell untill you know your way around.

---

If you've build qgis from source and you cant start it because it cant find its libraries follow the following:

Open the terminal and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /path/to/qgis/output/lib (ubuntu 12.04 doesn't use LD_LIBRARY_PATH by default, so it should be empty so you shouldn't be able to break anything - if you do just restart the shell), then start qgis by navigating to /path/to/qgis/output/bin and ./qgis

**Here's a List with the steps.**

1. $ cd ~/path/to/output/bin
2. $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/path/to/output/lib"
3. $ ./qgis

---

You can even create a script if you want:

1. $ touch run_qgis.sh
2. $ chmod +x run_qgis.sh
3. enter in the first line `#!/bin/bash`
4. insert the above steps from the previous list
5. run the script! (./run_qgis.sh)